# Is there any way to switch group legend position on phpbb 3.1.x forums?

Tags: phpbb3

For previous versions, there used to be a mod like [this](https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=576823).

As I have installed 3.1.9 version, have I missed an OOTB feature for changing the group legend order?

Comment: afaik that would need an extension writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the ACP > Users and groups > groups > Manage group positions

Sort legend by group name have to be on "No" value

In the next form, you can choose groups to be displayed and order them.

[image]